# How to use two custom list views on one activity in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I am trying to show two custom listviews on one activity. But I am confused how to handle onListItemClick and most important how I can set the ID

> @id/android:list

for both the lists on the same activity?

If any one have tried with two list views on single activity, any link, sample code will be helpful. Thanks in advance...

Comment: did you solved ?I have same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define two ListViews in your XML, like:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your code use this command to assign your Lists

```
ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
ListView list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
```

and for both of them set a different `onItemClickListener`, for example this way:

```
    list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //...

        }
    });
```

and you are done :) This way, your activity don't need to extend `ListActivity`, just `Activity`.

Comment: I have same problem can you help?

Comment: how can i refresh my custom adapter ?